# How to generate load on IIS?

Tags: c#, http, scalability, generator, wcf-rest

I want to start using load balancers, database replication and sharding, cloud computing. I know I can follow many tutorials, that's no problem, but I don't know how to generate sufficient traffic to load the web server. I want to see my test application working really slow and then apply some scaling techniques.

**Q** How can I generate huge load on my local IIS server? What tools can I use?

P.S. if it will help I want to use RESTful WCF service and No SQL DB/Cloud storage for a test app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several tools available, here are a couple of free ones:

- [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)
- [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)

Although these are both java tools, you can use them to generate load directed at IIS

Comment: +1 for JMeter. We use it for most of our load testing.  Grinder looks good, too.

Answer (score 2):

There was a great tool from microsoft called webstress.  They removed it from their servers, but I managed to find it and placed it [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10020780/releases/Microsoft_Web_Application_Stress_Tool.exe).

From my memory, it can do log/replay traffic, multiple machine generating requests, has decent reporting capabilities....

EDIT:

Friend found out another one: http://seleniumhq.org/

Comment: As I uploaded to the dropbox, I figured out that it is already there on the cloud, upload lasted half-a-second.  Popular tool :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use jMeter to record operations and orchestrate load on one or many clients. It requeres some setup but is both flexible and powerfull.

http://jmeter.apache.org/

Comment: I am sure I can use it with REST WCF, but do you think there might be a port to .NET, just for other .NET apps?

Comment: Hey - I don't think it is ported; it is an old project which contains a bunch of quite impressive features. I have used it successfully for testing aspx and WCF projects though, but a port would of course be welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Edition for doing  [Load Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182594.aspx).

The are also many other documents and articles on if you google it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it extensively, but [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) and [LoadUI](http://www.loadui.org/) work well together to do this.